# NullPointerException GoogleMaps in some devices

Tags: android, google-maps, nullpointerexception, fragment

I have an app with GoogleMap v2. In my device (Galaxy Nexus) works fine but in other phones it crash and I don't know why. My code:

```
public class Activity_Maps extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity {
private GoogleMap map = null;
    //...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
    setUpMapIfNeeded(); // Verify Google Maps and load it
    //...
    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);   // HERE CRASH !!!!!!!!!
    //...
    }

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    if (map == null) {
        if (isGoogleMapsInstalled()) {
            map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            Notification notification = new Notification(getBaseContext(),
                    "GoogleMaps", getResources().getString(
                            R.string.googlemaps_found));
            notification.show();
        } else {
            dialogNeedGoogleMap();
        }
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "map != null");
    }
}

public boolean isGoogleMapsInstalled() {
    try {
        getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(
                "com.google.android.apps.maps", 0);
        return true;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}

   /*
    * Go GooglePlay to install GoogleMap
    */
public void dialogNeedGoogleMap() {
    final String MARKET = "market://details?id=com.google.android.apps.maps";
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialog.setTitle(getResources().getString(
            R.string.googlemaps_need1));
    dialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(
            R.string.googlemaps_need2));
    dialogo.setCancelable(false);

    dialog.setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.ok),
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                            .parse(MARKET));
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            });

    dialog.setNegativeButton(getResources().getString(R.string.cancel),
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
    dialog.show();
}
```

My map in xml:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

I think crashes could come from devices without GoogleMap but in this case should show a dialog to give option to install or exit without load the map. In this case should show a dialog to give option to install it or exit.

I catch exception from GoogleAnalytics and all they are in the line:

```
 map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
```

I could catch this exception and show dialog of GoogleMaps but I can not understand how code comes until here. In my phone it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing the wrong check. Use [GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil.html#isGooglePlayServicesAvailable%28android.content.Context%29) instead of looking for unrelated application.

And put this line:

```
map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);   // HERE CRASH !!!!!!!!!
```

inside the check, not after it was performed. This code will execute unconditionally, so you will always get NPE on devices which have no Google Play Services installed.

You may also test this on your own device. Just uninstall Google Play Services.